# How do you get XCode 4 to build a Foundation command line tool that runs on both 32 and 64 bit?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I don't know if this question is specific to Foundation command line tools, but this is the scenario I need help on.

EDIT

Sorry, I really meant to ask: How do you get XCode 4 to generate a command line tool that is portable between 32 bit and 64 bit Macs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Build Settings value -- it sounds like you want it to be set to "Standard (32/64-bit Intel)".
Or you can paste this into the build settings directly:
`ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT)`

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 will not build for PPC anymore.  Intel only.

If you need a universal binary, you'll need to use Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: Sorry I misstated my question.